# Google map - how to create click event to scroll on to another div with class on the page

Tags: google-maps, maps

I've created map with multi pins and different image, I need to add to the click event scroll to the div with class .store

I've tried to follow example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple
but no luck

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: not sure how to change click event to find div and scroll to it

Answer (score 0):

you may use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('div.store').scrollIntoView();
  });
```